# How to Fix the Table Size in Mobile View on WordPress Website?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-shortcode

I'm working on a sports-related website on which I'm writing about different sports. I write articles about the cricket records of players. I include the table of the records in the post. The most of table consists of 3 to 5 columns. So when anyone visits the post on a mobile phone the record table is not properly viewed on the mobile. [Check here](https://sportsest.com/most-runs-in-the-t20-world-cup/). Tell me how I can show the complete table in the mobile view without any plugin. This is a WordPress website.

I want that some give me guide how to solve it or if have any code to put in the post and solve this issue also share it.

Comment: Use CSS media queries and change the width of the table.

Comment: Please refer to this article on [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table_responsive.asp) how to make table responsive... there are other methods as well. .. but it is one of them..

Comment: additionally i checked your link and found your theme uses bootstrap 3.3.1... hence you can also refer to the documentation [here](https://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.1/docs/css/#tables) for responsive tables